# How to I check that the length of text of an element is greater than 0 in nightwatch?

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

How to I check that the length of text of an element is greater than 0 in nightwatch?

I want to check the length of text of an element on a page to make sure it is greater than 0 using nightwatch.

Answer (score 8):

You can make your own custom command that uses browser.assert.

```
module.exports = {
  'Length of text should be greater zero': function(browser) {

    browser
      .url('..')
      .getText('#some-selector', function(result) {
        browser.assert.ok(result.value.length > 0);
      })
      .end();
  }
};
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!